# Multiple "classes" in same namespace, but in separate files

Tags: javascript, module-pattern, revealing-module-pattern

I have a namespace: `Foo.Bar.Baz` within which I have the `Qux` class. These were defined using the revealing module pattern:

```
Foo.Bar.Baz = (function ($) {  // the namespace/module

  function Qux() {             // the Qux "class" is contained in this namespace
  // ...
  }

  Qux.prototype.doStuff = function() {
  // ...
  }

  return {                     // public exports from this namespace
    Qux: Qux
  };

}(jQuery));
```

Now, in a separate file, I want to add the `Quux` class to this namespace. How do I do that? When I use the same pattern as above, it is ignored, as I guess the one is overwriting the other.

Comment: To what "namespace"? Do you want `Foo.Bar.Baz.Qux.Quux` or `Foo.Bar.Baz.Quux`? Terms like "namespace" and "module" are jargon and best avoided in a technical discussion. You are dealing with objects, so talk about objects. Jargon is often misinterpreted as it can mean different things to different people.

Comment: @RobG Everything here is jargon, including your "objects". I agree that misinterpretation is possible, though I doubt many would as it is assumed a developer knows the jargon and the misuse of the jargon (if he's experienced). What I am trying to achieve is `Foo.Bar.Baz.Quux`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out: as expected, the second file's module was overwriting the first as soon as it was loaded.

In each file, use this structure:

```
Foo.Bar.Baz = (function (module, $) { // redefine existing module

  function Qux() {                    // add Qux "class" to it
  // ...
  }


  var exports = {                     // revealing module pattern: define exports
    Qux: Qux,
    // etc.
  };
  $.extend(module, exports);          // merge modules
  return module;

}(Foo.Bar.Baz, jQuery));              // import existing module, and anything else
```

Use the same structure for the other files (which contain the same module but with different classes). It won't matter which is defined first.

Comment: That just seems to be a less efficient way of doing the same thing as my answer. Instead of creating an object just so you can use `extend` (which just copies properties across), just assign them directly: `module.Qux = Qux;`.

Comment: Perhaps, but this is a simple example, there could be lots of publically exported functions and variables. And the efficiency gain is miniscule, besides, I prefer the ease of readability and maintainability of seeing the revealing module pattern and knowing exactly what's going on without any headscratching.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've already assigned an object to `Baz`, you just need to create a new property:

```
Foo.Bar.Baz.Quux = (function() {
    function private() {}
    var privateVar = 'whatever';

    return function() {
        // access private and privateVar
    };
}());
```

Of course Quux doesn't have access to the private members of Qux, is that the issue?

#### Edit

If you want to pass in the object reference, you can do:

```
(function(module) {
    function private() {}
    var privateVar = 'whatever';

    module.Qux = function() {
      // whatever
    };

    module.Quux = function() {
      // different whatever
    };
}(Foo.Bar.Baz));
```

The two approaches are functionally equivalent.

Comment: No the private member access isn't a concern, what I needed was to have two classes in the same class/module/namespace/whatever. They each have access only to their own stuff. External code can see the classes and the "revealed" members only.